# Confused as to whether I should use commas or not

Tags: punctuation, commas

I am getting some gifts engraved for my wedding party and I can't decide whether to use commas or not. Should it be:

> Thank you Neil
>   for being our Usher

or:

> Thank you, Neil,
>   for being our Usher

I think the second option is correct but doesn't look quite right, probably due to being separated over two lines. Any advice would be greatly appreciated as once the engraving is done that's it.

Comment: I don't know whether to recommend commas or not, but I will comment that *if* I recommended commas, I would also definitely recommend putting a period after *Usher*. No point in doing things by halves; either no punctuation at all, or punctuation all the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In formal writing, it would be:

> Thank you, Neil, for being our usher.

But an engraving has less space available, so it's expected that you cut unnecessary punctuation, as you would in a newspaper headline.

If you'd like to omit the commas to make it less cluttered, I say go ahead and do it.